# MUI v5, breakpoints shorthand not working when customized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

I encountered an issue where theme breakpoints shorthand do not work when customized

```
display: { xs: 'none', lg: 'flex' },
```

this works fine in default theme configuration. but as soon as I add:

```
breakpoints: {
      values: {
        sm: 640,
        md: 768,
        lg: 1024,
        xl: 1280
      }
    },
```

the first line or any other props that use the shorthand for breakpoints do not work

I tried using

```
[theme.breakpoints.up('xl')]: {
  display: 'flex'
},
```

this one works fine withuot a doubt. It means that breakpoints are initialized. but why cant I use the above shorthands for individual props. is there any limitation etc? I checked the docs but didnt find anything....

Comment: have you created a Theme using these breakpoints and used provider to make all theme inherent from it

Comment: yes I did it. theme is working fine and even theme.breakpoints api is working fine as well. just the shorthand props are causing problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have found the solution

```
breakpoints: {
      values: {
        xs: 0,
        sm: 640,
        md: 768,
        lg: 1024,
        xl: 1280
      }
    },
```

I was missing xs value before. Dont know how it was causing issue but it solves the problem anyways ^^